# mysql select rowpairs by date and userid

Tags: mysql, row

I am looking for a way to change a columvalue of both values of a rowpair.
Finding the correct rowpair is done by grouping. The problem is that only one row_id is returned because of the grouping.

Case:
A trainer can have two events on one day.
If a customer plans a trainingevent, the trainer visits that customer so he cannot visit another customer for the second session.
A customer that plans a trainingevent, gets offered events that have a location with value 'Null' or with their customerid.
This way a customer can plan multiple sessions on one day while another customer cannot claim the second event when the first is at another client.
Events are claimed in two steps: first the status is changed to 'Pending' and the event gets an expiredate, in the next step the status is changed to 'Taken'.
When a pending events expires, the status is changed back to 'Open'.

Problem: The location cannot always be cleared. If the other event is taken or pending, the location cannot be cleared. When both events are 'open' the location for both must be cleared.

Design:
The events-table contains a colum 'location'.
If an event is planned, all 'location' fields for this day are set to the customerid;

```
eventid - orderid - eventdatetime - expiredate - status - location
2 - NULL - 12 december 2012  9:00 - NULL - open - 45
3 - 54   - 12 december 2012 13:00 - 23nov2012 - pending - 45
4 - 74   - 13 december 2012  9:00 - 23nov2012 - pending - 45
5 - 23   - 13 december 2012 13:00 - NULL - taken - 45
6 - NULL - 14 december 2012  9:00 - NULL - open - NULL
7 - NULL - 14 december 2012 13:00 - NULL - open - NULL
```

If eventid 3 expires, the status has to be set to 'open' and the location of eventid 2 AND 3 have to be set to NULL
If eventid 4 expires, the status has to be set to 'open but the location of eventid 4 AND 5 have to be left untouched

I do this in two queries:

query one:

```
update trainingevents
set orderid = null
set expiredate = null
set status = "open"
where expiredate > now()
```

query two:

```
update trainingevents
set location = null
set expiredate
where eventid in (
    select eventid from trainingevents
    where count(orderid)=0 and count(location)>0
    group by date_format(eventdatetime, only date)
)
```

I use grouping to find the pairs but grouping returns only one eventid.

Any suggestions to obtain both eventids?

Comment: If it were me, I'd simplify the entire issue and change the tables so you had eventdate and location with an id, the you could use that to twiddle with the status of the "sub-events" on that date.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update both rows, there is no need to group (assuming I'm understanding you correctly).

you could rewrite query two as this:

```
update trainingevents
set location = null
set expiredate = null
where eventid in (
    select eventid from trainingevents
    where orderid is null and location is not null
)
```

or, more simply

```
update trainingevents
set
location = null,
expiredate = null
where orderid is null and location is not null
```

Comment: Having been around on stackoverflow for a while now I see that this question was way too long and overly complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, caitriona! (better late than never). Quiet quick I reformulated my question in this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642058/) that gave me the answer.