# Update one row of a row pair, where both rows together meet certain criteria

Tags: mysql, row

How do I obtain both ids of a pair of rows with certain specs?

More specific:

```
id - spec1 - spec2 - spec 3
1    null    30 nov  34
2    null    30 nov  34
3    null     1 dec  35
4    75       1 dec  35
```

I want to update spec3 of the rows that have the same date and where none of the rows has a value for spec1.

In the case of this example:
I want to update row 1 and 2 -> same date, no values for spec1

I don't want to update row 3 and 4 -> same date BUT row 4 has a value for spec1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the id(s) from this query

select a.id id from tbl a,
    tbl b
    where 
    a.spec2 = b.spec2 and
    isnull(a.spec1)  and isnull(b.spec1) and
    a.id != b.id;

Comment: Great. Thanks! I hadn't thought of joining the table on itself!

Comment: glad to be of help.Please accept it if it solves you purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE my_table t1
  JOIN my_table t2
    ON t1.spec1 IS NULL
   AND t2.spec1 IS NULL
   AND t1.spec2 = t2.spec2
   AND t1.id    < t2.id
SET    t1.spec3 = 123,
       t2.spec3 = 456
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88167/1/0).

Comment: Great thanks!Why have you given the argument `t1.id<t2.id`? Doesn't `t1.id!=t2.id` make more sense?

Comment: @Sybren: Otherwise you will update the same records twice, once when `(t1.id, t2.id) = (1, 2)` and once when it `= (2, 1)`.